# Number of binary strings of length n with k adjacent ones

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

Consider a space $H_n$ of binary strings of $n$ variables. Let $B(n,k)$ be the set of strings with $k$ ones having also an other one on the right, i.e.

$$B(n,k) = \{s \in H_n \, \, \, s.t. \, \, \, \sum^{n-1}_{i=0} s_{i} s_{|i+1|_n} = k   \}, $$

where for simplicity I assumed also periodic boundaries with the modulus $n$.
For instance, for $k=n$ this number must be $1$, for $k=n-1$ there are $n$ such strings...

Is it possible to know what is the cardinality of $B(n,k)$ exactly, or at least the functional dependence of $B(n,k)$ on $k$, fixed $n$? Or does it rescale to a known function when we divide by the total number of strings $2^n$ ?

P.S. The boundary condition is not essential. Solutions to the same problem, without boundary condition would be also well appreciated.

Comment: What's $N(n,k)$?

Comment: Your index in the sum should start at $i=1$ since it refers to $s_{[i-1]}$ and you've only extended your length $n$ string to the left one unit below $1$ by putting $s_0=1$. I also don't think the subscript $n$ on the subscript $s_{[i]_n}$ is really necessary.

Comment: The prescription of placing a $1$ at index $0$, along with your "periodic boundaries mod $n$ condition, are conflicting. Consider e.g. the sequence $[1,1,0]$ for $n=3$ with your extra $1$ placed before it, then if we repeat mod 3 we get $[1,1,1,0,1,1,0,...]$ which is not periodic mod 3. I'd suggest just dropping the idea of putting an initial $1$ at $s_0$, and just saying the indices are mod $n$. Then you can keep the same definition of $B(n,k)$ and it is as if you arrange the binary digits around a circle and ask how many strings have $k$ cases of adjacent $1$'s.

Comment: JORIKI: I meant the total number of strings... it was a mistake and now it is correct.

COFFEMATH: I made it more clear. Now my sum starts at 0 and ends at n-1, so it is a sum over n terms. The modulus n is needed because when i=n-1, the term i+1 must be 0. In this case the string can be view as a circle. 

Now the periodic boundary condition should be well defined.

In any case also the solution of the problem without any boundary condition would be really appreciated.

Comment: The title of your question reminds me of questions about, e.g., tripletless binary strings of length $n$. That is: How many binary strings of length $n$ are there such that no digit (i.e., $0$ or $1$) appears three times consecutively? Of course, this is also broached with recurrence relations. I believe the answer in the example I've given is $2F(n+1) =$ twice the $(n+1)$st Fibonacci number. (Where $F(1) = 1, F(2) = 1, F(3) = 2,$ etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $C(n,k)$ be the number of strings of length $n$ having $k$ ones with another $1$ on the left, ending in $1$ and $D(n,k)$ be the number of strings of length $n$ having $k$ ones with another $1$ on the left, ending in $0$.  Then $B(n,k)=C(n,k)+D(n,k)$ and you have recurrences $C(n,k)=C(n-1,k-1)+D(n-1,k), D(n,k)=C(n-1,k)+D(n-1,k), D(1,0)=1, C(1,0)=1$.  This avoids any periodic boundary-it uses linear strings.  I ran some numbers but didn't see an obvious relation.

Answer (score 1):

By mere counting, the number $B(n,k)$ (without the periodic boundary) is given by

$$B(n,k)=2\, T(n,k,0) + T(n,k,1) + T(n,k,-1)\approx 4 \,T(n,k,0)$$

with

$$T(n,k,e) =\sum_{j}{k +j -1 \choose j-1}{n-k -j -1 \choose j-1 +e}$$

with the appropiate limits for the index of summation.

I've checked this agrees with Ross Millikan's answer. Some values:

$B(8,5)=9\\B(27,11)=5160560\\B(100,20)=67984278293083430807186562176$

I doubt this can be simplified more, even in its approximate form.
For large values of $n,k$, we'd be looking for asymptotics for sum of the form

$$\sum_{j=0}^{b/2} {a +j \choose j}{b - j \choose j}$$

which seems an interesting problem in itself, but, again, it does not look straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be expressed like this:

Let CB(n, k) be the number of binary strings of length n with k adjacent ones (n >= k + 1).
For k = 0, it is defined as Fibonacci:

*CB(n, 0) = CB(n-1, 0) + CB(n-2, 0)*

*CB(1, 0) = 2, CB(2, 0) = 3*

For k > 0, it is defined like this:

*CB(n, k) = CB(n-1, k) + CB(n-2, k) + CB(n-1, k-1) - CB(n-2, k-1)*

*CB(k+1, k) = 1, CB(k+2, k) = 2*

For me it was easier way to write (iterative) algorithm with O((k+1)*(n-k)) time complexity, and O(3*k) memory usage. I have found this question in search for better algorithm. I hear it can be calculated in O(n-k).

If somebody is interested, I could try to write good explanation.